# C# code works in Visual Studio 2019 but not in online compiler

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, compilation, mono

I am doing online tests. The code works perfectly at my Visual Studio 2019  but not when I submit it. Even other online compilers throw many compilation errors. The online test environment settings are: DMCS version of Mono C#, compiler version 4.6.2.0 with the flags: -optimize+ -r:System.Numerics {files}.

I tried to change .NET target framework to 4, but I don't get any errors on my computer. How can I configure Visual Studio to the same settings as above?

[image]

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace capgemini_kattis
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

```
        /*
        >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Task 2
        */
        bool isNumberOfCommandsRead = false;
        List<string> answer = new List<string>();
        string input = "????????????????????????????????";
        Char[] charArray = input.ToCharArray();
        int numberOfCommands = 0;
        string line;

        void CLEAR(int i)
        {
            charArray[i] = '0';
        }
        void SET(int i)
        {
            charArray[i] = '1';
        }
        void OR(int i, int j)
        {
            if (charArray[i] == '1' || charArray[j] == '1')
            {
                charArray[i] = '1';
            }
            else if (charArray[i] == '0' && charArray[j] == '0')
            {
                charArray[i] = '0';
            }
            else
            {
                charArray[i] = '?';
            }
        }
        void AND(int i, int j)
        {
            if (charArray[i] == '1' && charArray[j] == '1')
            {
                charArray[i] = '1';
            }
            else if (charArray[i] == '0' || charArray[j] == '0')
            {
                charArray[i] = '0';
            }
            else
            {
                charArray[i] = '?';
            }
        }

        while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (!isNumberOfCommandsRead)
            {
                numberOfCommands = Convert.ToInt32(line.Trim());
                isNumberOfCommandsRead = true;
                if (numberOfCommands == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }


            else
            {
                string[] split = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                switch (split[0].Trim().ToUpper())
                {
                    case "CLEAR":
                        CLEAR(Convert.ToInt32(split[1].Trim()));
                        numberOfCommands--;
                        break;

                    case "SET":
                        SET(Convert.ToInt32(split[1].Trim()));
                        numberOfCommands--;
                        break;

                    case "OR":
                        OR(Convert.ToInt32(split[1].Trim()), Convert.ToInt32(split[2].Trim()));
                        numberOfCommands--;
                        break;

                    case "AND":
                        AND(Convert.ToInt32(split[1].Trim()), Convert.ToInt32(split[2].Trim()));
                        numberOfCommands--;
                        break;
                }


                if (numberOfCommands == 0)
                {
                    Array.Reverse(charArray);
                    string sectionResult = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < (new string(charArray)).Length; i++)
                    {
                        sectionResult += charArray[i].ToString();
                        charArray[i] = '?';
                    }
                    answer.Add(sectionResult);
                    sectionResult = null;
                    isNumberOfCommandsRead = false;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (string s in answer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can change language version somewhere in the build settings of your project if that's what you mean.

Comment: @Silvermind the thing is that I change those but no idea how to match the above specifications from Mono DMCS...

Comment: You might be using some C# 8 features and not realizing it. Why don't you show some code that's causing issues? Or since it's mono you might be using some Windows libraries that are incompatible. Again, just guessing without code.

Comment: @gilliduck I added the code. Maybe that would help, thanks. May it be better to install Mono on my Windows and try that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that [Repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/csharp) is compiling in Mono C#, compiler version 4.6.2.0. It helped to find the issues and fix.